# Status bar color does not match navigation bar

Tags: ios, statusbar

I have a view controller I am presenting modally. I want the status bar color to match the navigation bar color.

I have set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES because I don't want this change across the entire application.

I am setting self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor but this is only changing the navigation bar color. The status bar remains a lighter color.

I have tried various combinations of setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate and preferredStatusBarStyle but none have any effect.

[image]

View controller is launched like so:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchController];

navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: how you create the navigationbar?

Comment: View controller is embedded in a navigation controller. Code added to question.

Comment: do you mean this:http://wx2.sinaimg.cn/mw690/928504ccgy1fc621a5tsdj20hs0ws3z7.jpg

Comment: Yes, that's how I want it to look

Comment: Okay, I am sure the issue is caused by your wrong step.I will give my steps to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My steps are below, check where you go wrong:

1. Create 2 view controller like below, you can let vc1 embed in a navigation controller:

[image]

2. In the vc1, you drag a action of the button:

[image]

Code is below:

```
- (IBAction)clickAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController2 *searchController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchController];

    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

3. Then in the vc2, you set the title:

[image]

Comment: I found the problem. Someone had added this into one of the methods in viewDidLoad: self.navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true;